# how to compare many lists with same number of elements

Tags: python, list, max

i have a measurement system. it generates 4 output values every second. a list of 4 values (eg. [30, 45, 70, 10]). when i press the calculate button, it should compare the values. let's say i pressed calculate button after  3 seconds. so it is gonna compare 3 lists. comparing means comparing the elements in the same position. for example  [10, 5, 23, 24] and [22, 35, 45, 12] are two lists. position zero element in the first list (here 10) should compare with position zero in the second list (here 22) and print the high value among those two. same way other position elements. How to do this. how to save all lists and compare?

```
# for demonstration, I am using  random number generator
import tkinter as tk
import random

measure_status = True

def readValues():
    if measure_status :
        outputs = [0]*0
        outputs.append(rand.randrange(0,100,1))
        outputs.append(rand.randrange(0,100,1))
        outputs.append(rand.randrange(0,100,1))
        outputs.append(rand.randrange(0,100,1))
       # do i need another variable to save all the list to compare
    win.after(1000, readValues)

def calc_max():

    global measure_status 
    measure_status = False  #stopping meaasurement.
# rest of the code here? how to compare lists?


win = Tk()

calc_btn  = tk.Button(win, text = "Calculate", command=calc_max )
calc_btn.grid(row=4, column=4)

win.after(1000, readValues)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try reading on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center. Specifically the part about creating a [minimal. reproductive example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should minimize the question for the specific problem in hand. For example, there is nothing related to `tkinter` in your question, or to the whole code for that matter...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` and `max`:

```
def get_max_list(list_of_lists):
    """
    Returns a list of max values for the zips of list_of_lists.
    Assumes each list is the same length.
    """
    return [max(x) for x in zip(*list_of_lists)]

    # The above is equivalent to:
    # result = []
    # for x in zip(l1, l2, l3):
    #     result.append(max(x))
    # print(*result) # Just prints each entry in result.

l1 = [10, 5, 23, 24]
l2 = [22, 35, 45, 12]
l3 = [0, 22, 123, 33]
lists = [l1, l2, l3] # our list of lists example input
print(*get_max_list(lists))
```

Output:

```
22 35 123 33
```

Comment: how do I save the lists? as i mentioned in the question, I have new list every second. seems like I should append new list and it might end up in a list of lists! ??

Comment: I am confused. Do you want to save this out? or save a different output?  The input to the code I provided should be a list of lists and the output to my code is a singular list.

Comment: here you clearly named the lists l1, l2 and l3. In my case what is happening is, a new list with 4 elements will be there  every second. for example,  first second [10,20,30,40] and in next  the second [33, 17, 2, 28] and in the next second [48, 27, 16, 28] and so on until I press Calculate button. Now I have to compare three lists. (it can be many until I press calculate button).

Comment: got it. Thanks ;)